# When to use an equal area projection using zonal statistics

Tags: python, zonal-statistics, equal-earth-projection

I have a shapefile called "Africa" with cells around all the African continent. I also have a raster file of population around the world, called "population". I would like to do a zonal stats with my shapefile and my population raster to obtain the sum of population in each cell.

I am doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import CRS
import rasterio
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
from rasterio.mask import mask

Africa = gpd.read_file(data_directory + 'GridCells/ccode_GID.shp')
population = rasterio.open(pop_ag_1990)

Africa.crs
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World.
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich


population.profile:
'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': -9999.0, 'width': 2160, 'height': 1920, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(0.0416666666667, 0.0, -30.0,
       0.0, -0.0416666666667, 40.00000000006399), 'tiled': False, 'interleave': 'band'


#I do the zonal stats in the following way:

population_array, population_transform = mask(population, shapes=Africa.geometry, crop=True, nodata=np.nan)

zs1 = zonal_stats(Africa, population_array[0], affine=population_transform, stats=['sum'], nodata=np.nan)
Africa['population'] = [x['sum'] for x in zs1]
```

I think my raster and my shapefile are in the EPSG: 4326 (same projected coordinate system). I have been reading that instead of having both of them in the same projection, I should have them in an equal area projection. Must I do that?

I mask the raster to store the values in an array and using the transform to relate each value to a coordinate, but I am not sure if that is enough to take into account the size of my cells. Is it?

Comment: Wgs84 is not a projected CRS

Comment: Do you refer to the Africa shapefile? I thought that the CRS is what says where the shapefile/raster is located and how to flatten in to a geographic space. Am I wrong?

Comment: that's right, but EPSG:4326 doesn't make any change to the coordinates - its a so called Plate Carree projection

Comment: So, is it possible to infer from your comment that having the same CRS (the raster and the shapefile) is not enough to do a proper zonal statistics as I am doing? My intuition says that if both of them have the same CRS, they should be flatten in the same plane, but it is not clear to me if I am right or not.

Comment: that they share a projection is necessary but not sufficient for good analysis. You mention equal-earth-projection in your tags but WSG84 (EPSG:4326) is not one of those projections. You probably want to find an equal **area** projection to carry out zonal analysis

Comment: If the CRS identify how is located and a method to flatten to a geographic space, I really do not see why a equal-earth projection is needed. Is there one recommended for Africa?

Comment: All projections distort in some way, you need to pick one that distorts the thing you are interested in least

Comment: I don't believe you need an equal area CRS to do zonal stats.  Particularly as by reprojecting your raster, you are resampling it and altering the values.  You need an equal area CRS when you are using distance or area calcs.

Comment: Thanks @user2856 ! Very helpful. When you say using distance or area calculations, do you mean calculating areas of different polygons or do you mean raster's with for example, instead of population as I asked, doing a zonal stats with raster's which contains information about harvested area?

Comment: I'm talking about polygon area or raster based cost-distance type analyses.  Your raster has a value assigned to a pixel. I don't know how that value was derived, but you may have metadata or a report that discusses the process.  Generally speaking, area calculations like that would have been done before assigning the value to the pixel and would have taken projection into account.